# Silverlight 5 web cam capture: Two capture sources on the same device

Tags: silverlight, webcam, video-capture

I tried to attach the same Video Source Device (the WEB CAM) to two different CaptureSource objects but it looks like that want work.

The system throws an exception:  A device attached to the system is not functioning. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)

I think the web cam is locked on first CaptureSource.

Does anybody has an idea how to display two images from the same Device but from different capture source? I wanted to use a simple CaptureSource on one side and MediaStremSource with some filtering on the other side to see differences between original and filtered video source.

I wanted to use the plain CaptureSource because it's performance is better than MediaStreamSource. MediaStreamSource loses time when raises OnSample Event which is not happening with CaptureSource.

Answer (score 0):

I know this exception, When you work on debug mode silverlight fails.
Run project by Ctrl+F5. (Release mode)

In addition use ask for permission methods this will display permission window for camera.

Answer (score 0):

It is very capable, just did it myself. However, in experimenting with different cameras and different inputs....  2 MS LifeCams connected to USB3 = same error. Connecting to USB2 hub to USB2 MB works like a charm. Also, if I run something like ActiveCam and it crashes, may need a reboot. Oh, you will need to use 2 capture sources.... but can still ask permission once.

Also remember not to use DefaultCaptureDevice but:

```
var dev1 = CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetAvailableVideoCaptureDevices()[0];
var dev2 = CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetAvailableVideoCaptureDevices()[1];
```

With perhaps better naming conventions and logic to check if devices exist etc...

Comment: I asked if it is possible to capture the same web cam (same device), same source using two CaptureSources ...